# How can I write the integral for the volume of this set?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

I am doing my homework and I got to one exercise where I have to write the integral for this set:

$$B=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : \sqrt{x^2+y^2}<z<2-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}; y>0\}$$

using cylindrical coordinates.

The problem is that I am having a hard time to interpret this set. I tried to draw the region but I guess I did not draw it the right way.

Can someone explain me how to interpret this particular set?

Thanks!

Comment: Both of the bounds are shaped by a cone, one going up, and the other going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the bounds are shaped by a cone, one going up, and the other going down.  Where they intersect is also interesting; setting one equal to the other, you get
$$2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2$$
or the unit circle.  Given you have the bounds on $z$ laid out, and the planar bounds are within the unit circle, the integral looks like
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1\int_{r}^{2-r}rdzdrd\theta$$

Comment: Thank you! But isn´t the plan where they intersect: 2-Z = Z <=> Z = 1? And just one more thing, think the θ integral should be from 0 to PI right? Because y > 0.